# Rails Undefined Constant: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rescue

I have the following code in my Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :record_not_found
  private
  def record_not_found
    render :text => "404 Not Found", :status => 404
  end
end
```

When I run it (actually I run `rake db:migrate`) I get the error `uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.  This seems too simple -- HELP!

Comment: It seems that are something wrong with some of your migration files.

Comment: Migration files worked great until I added the 'rescue_from' and worked again when i added 'require active_record/errors'.  Still wondering why that was required, as none of the examples I found online had that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It needed `require 'active_record/errors'`, which I didn't see on **any** of the examples I found when I googled.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to look carefully at the error. Similar errors can easily be mistyping, e.g. using `ActiveRecord::NotFound` vs. `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` will cause a similar error.

Comment: Although it doesn't apply in this case, I would endorse that idea generally.